# constructor with string and bad_alloc check

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, constructor, exception

I am a C++ beginner and I am writing a class in C++ and I am using `std::string`.
How do I handle `bad_alloc` exception?
Can I do:

```
Temp::Temp(const string name) :
{
    try {
        name(name);
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc& a) {
        cout << "bad alloc error" << endl;
    }
}
```

or should I do

```
Temp::Temp(const string name) :
 name(name)
{
    catch(std::bad_alloc& a) {
        cout << "bad alloc error" << endl;
    }
}
```

I want to catch the exception so that I would be able to prevent memory leak, and then maybe throw it again.
Also when I use `x.assaing(y)` from `std::string` do I have to check for `bad_alloc` exception too? (If I want to handle memory leaks.)
I am looking for a way without smart pointers (we didn't learn it yet).

Comment: Just: `Temp::Temp(const string name) : name(name) {  }`

Comment: There won't be a memory leak in the posted code.

Comment: More often than not you catch `bad_alloc` in `main`, print a message and exit. Memory leaks are handled not so much by *catching* exceptions as by writing exception-safe code. Simple code like `Temp::Temp(const string & name) : name(name) {}` is exception-safe, no need to do anything extra.

Comment: i want to add more fields and create an array of Temps in another class so if an alloc fails i want to print a massage or maybe throw a different exception to clear the array(if it is possible-i dont want to catch the bad_alloc in the other class)

Comment: @M.ams - If you get a `bad_alloc`, that's because no memory could be allocated. So nothing to leak.  :-)  And if you create an array (or `vector`) of strings, an exception half-way through will make the compiler revert everything, and no leak there either. So read up on exception safety guarantees, and don't try too hard to do things manually.  :-)

Comment: The short answer, as others have said, is "you don't". If construction of the `std::string` in a constructor initialiser list throws, the C++ standard guarantees no memory leak AND the body of your constructor is not called. Similarly, if you need collections of objects, use appropriate standard containers and initialise them in the initialiser list.  Again, if an exception is thrown (in either sizing the container or initialising the individual elements) then the standard guarantees no leaks. Doing things manually, as you are, is an effective way to cause leaks when an exception occurs.

Comment: You write your code in an exception-safe way. This is something you learn to do, not something that happens automatically if you catch every possible exception.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a member of type `std::string` via constructor in a [*member initializer list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) won't cause memory leak.

```
#include <string>
struct Temp
{
   Temp (const std::string& name): name(name) {}
   std::string name;
};

Temp t ("yourname");
std::cout << t.name; // yourname
```

**UPDATE:** *(suggested by @Deduplicator)*
 
If only using one ctor, might as well use `std::string_view` which is a:

> constant contiguous sequence of `char`-like objects

Like:

```
#include <string_view>
struct Temp
{
   Temp (std::string_view name): name(name) {}
   std::string name;
};

Temp t ("yourname");
std::cout << t.name; // yourname
```

Comment: If only one ctor, then better: `Temp(std::string_view name) : name(name) {}`

Comment: Hm, `string_view` is always passed by value, if you can choose, as it is a light-weight view, not a potentially heavy container.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I see. and is it always `const` -(*refer to a constant contiguous sequence of char-like objects*)?

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) Also interesting is [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), to date (pre-c++20) only available as `gsl::span`.

Answer (score 0):

If string construction does throw bad_alloc there is very little you can do to recover from it. You certainly should not be wrapping each construction of a string in a try-block. Instead you should allow the exception to bubble up to a higher level, such as your main function, catch it there, report the error somehow, and probably terminate the program. In general, you want to catch exceptions at the highest  possible level that they can sensibly be handled.

Comment: hi, this is for an exercise without a main so i am expected to catch the exception and handle it (clear all memory and exit the program) without submitting a main.is there a way to catch the exception in the constructor?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the exercise. And  it's actually quite unlikely that bad_alloc will ever be thrown during string construction.

Comment: but if i wont handle the bad_alloc there will be a memory leak. so i need to catch the exception and handle it and then throw it again so that when we exit the program(with the main) all memory will be clear.

Comment: There won't be any memory leak.

Comment: this is not the only class, for example there is another class with an array of Temps.so if in one of the Temp allocation there will be a bad_alloc, i need to clear the array first. or am i wrong and memory leak is not possible here?

Comment: It depends on how you are allocating the array (which should be a vector, which would be leak-proof). If you are manually allocating the array, then it's in that code that you could catch any bad_alloc for strings, but it's really not worth it.